# @output - calling a function in parent component from child - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a parent component and a child component.
There is a form & button in child component. When clicked it adds the form details in DB and shows the result of successful addition and redirects to the parent component page.

I want the result to be displayed on the parent page when its redirected to it.

here is what I have:

**parent-component.html**

```
    <div>
        <apm-configuration-list (AddUpdateConfigEvent) = AddUpdateConfigEvent($event)></apm-configuration-list>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-1">
        <alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true"
            [dismissOnTimeout]="alert.timeout" (onClosed)="closeAlert(i)">
            <div [innerHTML]="alert?.msg"></div>
        </alert>
    </div>
```

**Child-component.ts**

```
Output() AddUpdateConfigEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

public updateConnection() {
        this.adService.addAdConfiguration(this.adConfigurationObj, this.isEditMode).subscribe((response) => {
            if (response.Status === ResultStatus.Success) {
                this.AddUpdateConfigEvent.emit();
                this.router.navigate(['/configuration/groups-permissions'], { state: { isAdConfig: true } });
                
            } else {
                this.alerts.push(
                    {
                        msg: response.Details,
                        type: 'danger',
                        timeout: 3000
                    });
                }
        });
    }
```

**parent-component.ts**

```
public AddUpdateConfigEvent(event: any) {
        this.alerts.push(
            {
                msg: 'Configuration added successfully!',
                type: 'success',
                timeout: 3000
            });
    }
```

it is just redirecting the the path(parent component page) but not showing any alert.

How can i display alert at the parent page?

Comment: In examle Child-component.ts you don't have the `@` symbol before `Output()`. It will be `@Output()`. And you have space between `(AddUpdateConfigEvent) = AddUpdateConfigEvent($event)` - it wil be `(AddUpdateConfigEvent)=AddUpdateConfigEvent($event)`

Comment: thanks. but that didn't solve the issue

Comment: Maybe you have some error in console? Maybe you component use `OnPush` strategy. You have `this.alerts` in `parent` and in `child`. Maybe you push in `child alerts`, but in template you use `parent alerts`.

Comment: You're pushing an object inside your alerts array. `innerHtml` is used to show `HTML` content, so make sure the `response.Details` actually has `html` content in your child component.